# Would symptoms differ from eating virus contaminated food versus breathing in virus?

Tags: virology, coronavirus

Would symptoms differ from eating virus contaminated food versus breathing in virus?

The COVID-19 causes respiratory symptoms and I guess that is because people are breathing in virus droplets in their lungs.
But if you would swallow COVID-19 contaminated food and avoid breathing in the virus would that cause other symptoms like stomach pain or diarrhea?

Comment: SE Biology is a question and answer site — not a discussion site or a site for floating ideas. It is concerned with the mechanisms of biological processes, not medical or social aspects of biology. For one of these reasons I think  that your question on the coronavirus outbreak is off-topic here. Question of a medical nature might be on-topic at SE Medical Sciences. Otherwise you are advised to consult more appropriate reputable sources for such information, some of which are listed [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/information-about-coronaviruses/4036#4036).

Comment: @David Can I remove the COVID-19 from my question and only keep "Would symptoms differ from eating virus contaminated food versus breathing in virus?". I believe that question is about biology but I could be wrong.

Comment: Does the virus genetic code decide which organs to infect or does it depend where it infects initially?

Comment: Please transfer your question to a site that deals with medical questions. Or read the Sources I suggested. And the virus uses the same genetic code as its host. The complete genetic information for an organism is termed the genome. The genetic code is a 64-word cypher used to transcribe the mRNA for that portion of the genome that encodes protein. Check it out on Wikipedia.

Comment: @David I posted the question now at https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21741/would-symptoms-differ-from-eating-virus-contaminated-food-versus-breathing-in-vi but I need to think how I can make this question non medical and more biology oriented.

Comment: If you have posted it on Medical Sciences you should now delete it from here according to SE policy.